# httplib request via proxy to api.github.com gives 502 error

Tags: python, http-proxy, httplib

I am trying to make a request using `httplib` through a proxy server to `api.github.com`, but getting `502` error. FYI, `curl, requests, wget` work fine.

```
c = HTTPSConnection(host='192.168.1.1', port='8080')
c.set_tunnel('api.github.com', headers={'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic ...'})
rh =  {'Authorization': 'Basic ...', 'User-Agent': 'prboard/Python'}
url = '/users/kumarvaradarajulu/repos'
c.request('GET', url, 'null', rh)
r = c.getresponse()
```

I get status as `502` and output as something like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--\n\nHello future GitHubber! I bet you\'re here to remove those nasty inline styles,\nDRY up these templates and make \'em nice and re-usable, right?\n\nPlease, don\'t. https://github.com/styleguide/templates/2.0\n\n-->\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n    <title>Unicorn! &middot; GitHub</title>\n
```

Comment: Maybe a dump of real request sent to the server and its response will shed some light on what is happening. Currently, there's no [mcve] - we don't have your proxy.

Comment: Trying to get that not able to get it, do you have any suggestions on how to ge the dump, I am on Centos 6.7